# How to count the number of times a button is clicked Python(tkinter)

Tags: python, button, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am writing a program for school, and I have to make a maths quiz, the quiz needs to be out of 10 questions.  I have made a button that is defined with a command that generates a new questions, clears the text box, get the answer from the dictionary, and inserts the new question into the textbox.  At the moment the user can press the button as many times as they want.  I dont actually know how to count or monitor the amount of times a button in tkinter has been pressed.  I would be very grateful if someone could provide me with some code for Python(3.1.4) that I could use to count the amount of times the button has been pressed.

Comment: You need to try this first.  If you have, post what you tried.  If not, try it then come back.  Even if I wanted to write this for you, I couldn't without seeing the context that this will fit into.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want (it counts the number of button presses and prints it):

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.bttn_clicks = 0
        self.create_widget()

    def create_widget(self):
        self.bttn = Button(self)
        self.bttn['text'] = "Total Clicks: 0"
        self.bttn['command'] = self.update_count
        self.bttn.grid()

    def update_count(self):
        self.bttn_clicks += 1
        self.bttn['text'] = "Total Clicks: " + str(self.bttn_clicks)

root = Tk()
root.title("Click Counter")
root.geometry('200x50')

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

That is the base of your program, you will have to put this code to use the way you want to yourself, as I don't have access to your source code.

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable in a global or class instance scope and a function that has access to the scope of the variable that increments the variable when called.  Set the function as the `command` attribute of the `Button` so that the function is called when the button is clicked.